# concating 2 unicode strings - how to do that?

Tags: c, windows, unicode, driver

I have 2 unicode strings which I like to concat.

everytime I try to concat using RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString it telling me "STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL", even though im increasing my destination unicodestring.length to big numbers.

what is the method to concat 2 unicode strings ? thanks

Comment: im programming a driver for windows, in c programming language

Comment: Maybe this is obvious to other people, but what encoding of unicode are you using? This has, I think, some bearing on how you would go about calculating the correct amount of memory to allocate for the new concatted string.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should change MaximumLength, not Length of the destination buffer.

Comment: And of course, make sure MaximumLength is accurate by allocating enough memory.

Comment: UTF-16 can be 4 bytes per char.

Comment: UTF-8 can also use up to 4 bytes per character.  

According to the online docs, "RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString copies bytes from the source up to the length of the destination buffer. "

So your worst case is (<Destination max character count> + <Source  max character count>) * 4.

And have you allocated the memory already or just declared the size?